# `execvp()` seems to not be completing the path search

Tags: c, shell, command-line, system

TL;DR -- what sorts of things might cause an `execvp` call to not fully function/ search the path properly?

I'm on the tail end of building a rudimentary shell with some quality of life features that I've added over time e.g. history, alias's, and completions. I built those features on top of a functional shell that had a working $PATH search for execution e.g. typing in "ls -la" produced the desired behavior. As you might imagine, I accomplished this just using `execvp`. (This is written in C if it's not already clear)

I have not changed any of my tokenizing logic and have ensured that the file name is correct; in particular, `execvp` was producing the desired behavior before I had added these features to my REPL. `echo "hello"` still produces a tokenized `char **xyz` and the first token is indeed `echo`, null-terminated, and so on. That is, my call still looks like, with variables filled-in, `... execvp("echo", argv);` after which I call `perror`, which should only trigger when something has gone awry. Each time I just run the above command, though, since I've added in these features, it returns a failure with the `no such file or directory` --- before I added these features in though, the behavior was as desired. I'll note, though, that running `/bin/echo "hello"` runs as expected. Examples are WLOG.

I'm not sure where I should even start looking for errors, and my Google-fu has been mostly fruitless: any suggestions?

I'm initially going to omit code because it totals to several hundred lines and a MWE would not be particularly minimal in addition to my desires to keep this general rather than very particular to my code, though I'm not sure what's causing this. My repository is public and up-to-date, and I'm happy to post any code here.

EDIT:
I knew I wasn't explicitly editing the PATH variable, etc., but this block of code was the problem:

```
  // Grab $PATH from env
  char *pathvar = getenv("PATH");

  if (pathvar) {
    char *path;
    int i;

    // tokenize on colon to get paths
    // then use that immediately to 
    // scandir, and add everything in 
    // there to the completions system

    path = strtok(pathvar, ":");
    while (path) {
      struct dirent **fListTemp;
      int num_files = scandir(path, &fListTemp, NULL, alphasort);
      // only adding the names that are completely composed of 
      // lower case letters; completions are done using a naive
      // Trie Node structure that only supports lowercase letters 
      // for now... e.g. g++ does not work, and the '+' leads to 
      // a seg-fault. Same holds for . and ..
      for (i = 0; i < num_files; i++) {
        char *curr = fListTemp[i]->d_name;
        if (strcmp(curr, ".")==0 || strcmp(curr, "..")==0){
          continue;
        } else if (notalpha(curr)) {
          continue;
        } else {
          str_tolower(curr);
          tn_insert(completions, curr);
        }
      }
      for (i = 0; i < num_files; i++) {
        free(fListTemp[i]);
      }
      free (fListTemp);
      path = strtok(NULL, ":");
    }
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "{wsh @ init} -- $PATH variable could not be found?");
  }
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, I can only suggest running your tests under `strace -f -eexecve` so you can see what exactly `execvp` is doing and why it might be malfunctioning for some program names but not others.

Comment: Probably worth making sure you haven't somehow modified the environment variable `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments... was related somewhat to both. See the solution I came to. Did not know that `getenv` was a pointer directly to the string in the environment, which seems to have been the source of this bug.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

> ```
>    The getenv() function returns a pointer to the value in the
>    environment, or NULL if there is no match.
> ```

so my original code was indeed tampering with the PATH variable. The solution I came up with quickly was just to create a copy of that string and use that to parse through the PATH instead:

```
  // Grab $PATH from env
  char *pathvar = getenv("PATH");
  char *pathvar_cpy = strcpy(pathvar_cpy, pathvar);

  if (pathvar_cpy) {
    char *path;
    int i;
    path = strtok(pathvar_cpy, ":");
    while (path) {
      // Scan directory
      struct dirent **fListTemp;
      int num_files = scandir(path, &fListTemp, NULL, alphasort);

      for (i = 0; i < num_files; i++) {
        char *curr = fListTemp[i]->d_name;
        if (strcmp(curr, ".")==0 || strcmp(curr, "..")==0){
          continue;
        } else if (notalpha(curr)) {
          continue;
        } else {
          str_tolower(curr);
          tn_insert(completions, curr);
        }
      }
      for (i = 0; i < num_files; i++) {
        free(fListTemp[i]);
      }
      free (fListTemp);
      path = strtok(NULL, ":");
    }
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "{wsh @ init} -- $PATH variable could not be found?");
  }
```

Comment: Consider editing the code that causes the problem _into the question_ (where it should have been included as part of a [mre] in the first place) and leaving the answer in the answer.